# Macro to Protect Sheet With Allow Inserting of Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have prepared the below macro to unprotect a sheet, sort the data, then protect the sheet again.

It works perfectly except, in my original protection setting I allowed users to insert rows, but when the macro reprotects the sheet it stops users from doing this.

Can someone give me some points to get the protection to allow the inserting of rows?

```
Sub CustSort1()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "password"
Range("a14").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("a14"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range( _
    "k14"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
    Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
    xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
    DataOption3:=xlSortNormal
Range("a14").Select
ActiveSheet.Protect "password"
End Sub
```

Thanks for help ind advance.

Answer (score 4):

There are a bunch of flags that can be set after the `ActiveSheet.Protect` statement, including whether or not to allow inserting rows.  An example:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True , AllowInsertingRows:=True
```